# Boost 1.48.0 upgrade_to_unique_lock on Linux: Has something changed since 1.47 or I do something wrong?

Tags: c++, boost, locking, boost-thread

I have a small [cpp source](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudServer/src/cf-fs/fs_map.cpp) and [h source](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudServer/src/cf-fs/fs_map.h) files with some class. It uses [shared mutexes and shared locks](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/thread.html). It compiles on windows with no errors with boost 1.48.0. It also compiled on linux (with boost 1.47 before). But now having code like this:

```
 boost::shared_mutex mut_;
 //...
 boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(mut_);
 boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniqueLock(lock);
```

results in strange errors:

```
==== Building cf-fs (debug) ====
Creating bin/obj/Debug/cf-fs
fs_concurrent_queued_map.cpp
fs_map.cpp
In file included from ../../src/cf-util/http_utils_inl.h:1,
                 from ../../src/cf-util/http_utils.h:104,
                 from ../../src/cf-fs/fs_map.h:13,
                 from ../../src/cf-fs/fs_map.cpp:1:
../../src/cf-util/http_utils.h:105:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive
In file included from ../../src/cf-fs/fs_map.h:13,
                 from ../../src/cf-fs/fs_map.cpp:1:
../../src/cf-util/http_utils.h:105:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive
In file included from ../../../boost_libraries/install-dir/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:12,
                 from ../../../boost_libraries/install-dir/include/boost/thread/mutex.hpp:16,
                 from ../../../boost_libraries/install-dir/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:12,
                 from ../../../boost_libraries/install-dir/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:17,
                 from ../../../boost_libraries/install-dir/include/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from ../../src/cf-fs/fs_map.h:10,
                 from ../../src/cf-fs/fs_map.cpp:1:
../../../boost_libraries/install-dir/include/boost/thread/locks.hpp: In constructor ‘boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<Mutex>::upgrade_to_unique_lock(boost::upgrade_lock<Mutex>&) [with Mutex = boost::shared_mutex]’:
../../src/cf-fs/fs_map.cpp:33:   instantiated from here
../../../boost_libraries/install-dir/include/boost/thread/locks.hpp:926: error: call of overloaded ‘move(boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex>&)’ is ambiguous
../../../boost_libraries/install-dir/include/boost/thread/detail/move.hpp:44: note: candidates are: typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_convertible<T&, boost::detail::thread_move_t<T> >, boost::detail::thread_move_t<T> >::type boost::move(T&) [with T = boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex>]
../../../boost_libraries/install-dir/include/boost/move/move.hpp:294: note:                 typename boost::move_detail::disable_if<boost::has_move_emulation_enabled<T>, T&>::type boost::move(T&) [with T = boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex>]
../../../boost_libraries/install-dir/include/boost/thread/locks.hpp: In destructor ‘boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<Mutex>::~upgrade_to_unique_lock() [with Mutex = boost::shared_mutex]’:
../../src/cf-fs/fs_map.cpp:33:   instantiated from here
../../../boost_libraries/install-dir/include/boost/thread/locks.hpp:932: error: call of overloaded ‘move(boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex>&)’ is ambiguous
../../../boost_libraries/install-dir/include/boost/thread/detail/move.hpp:44: note: candidates are: typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_convertible<T&, boost::detail::thread_move_t<T> >, boost::detail::thread_move_t<T> >::type boost::move(T&) [with T = boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex>]
../../../boost_libraries/install-dir/include/boost/move/move.hpp:294: note:                 typename boost::move_detail::disable_if<boost::has_move_emulation_enabled<T>, T&>::type boost::move(T&) [with T = boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex>]
make[1]: *** [bin/obj/Debug/cf-fs/fs_map.o] Ошибка 1
make: *** [cf-fs] Ошибка 2
```

Do I have something wrong in my code that shall not compile and how to fix it or get around it?

Comment: I think it's this issue: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6141

Comment: Yes. Looks like it is. Can any one provide any way how to get around it (not by getting rid or shared locks)?

Comment: You'll have to go into the Boost source and disable Boost.Move or fix the bug described in that ticket.

Answer (score 2):

```
--- a/locks.hpp 2011-12-05 12:26:11.650309054 +0400
+++ b/locks.hpp 2011-12-05 12:27:25.905311415 +0400
@@ -923,13 +923,13 @@
         upgrade_to_unique_lock& operator=(upgrade_to_unique_lock&);
     public:
         explicit upgrade_to_unique_lock(upgrade_lock<Mutex>& m_):
-            source(&m_),exclusive(move(*source))
+            source(&m_),exclusive(move(detail::thread_move_t<upgrade_lock<Mutex> >(*source)))
         {}
         ~upgrade_to_unique_lock()
         {
             if(source)
             {
-                *source=move(exclusive);
+                *source=move(detail::thread_move_t<unique_lock<Mutex> >(exclusive));
             }
         }
```